# Mouse and Keyboard (over KVM switch) stopped working after Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, mouse, 20.04

I use Ubuntu over a Manhattan KVM switch (8-port HDMI) that worked perfectly with Ubuntu 18.04. I performed an update from 18.04 to 20.04 and my mouse and keyboard (connected over the KVM switch) stopped working.

I tried to reproduce the issue with another system and got the same: not-working keyboard and mouse.

`lsusb` shows the KVM-switch as Logitech Unifying Receiver.

Do I need to load a specific kernel module?

Currently `logitech-djreceiver` is loaded according the `dmesg` output. I did attach another mouse and keyboard. These make use of hid-generic and work.
Did anyone face a similar situation? Are there any ideas for solving the issue?

Comment: I tried the live system of Ubuntu 20.04 and get the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

If removing the kernel module fixes the issue, why not just blacklist the entire module from loading at boot?

```
$ sudo su
# echo "blacklist hid_logitech_dj" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
# update-initramfs -u
```

Then reboot, and it shouldn't load the module any further while booting.

Answer (score 0):

The vendor and product id of the KVM switch are 046D:C534. The driver hid_logitech_dj shows that id when running modinfo.

A workaround:
I created a shellscript /root/bin/rmlogitech-dj.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
/sbin/rmmod hid_logitech_dj
```

I run that script @reboot in cron as root:

```
@reboot /root/bin/rmlogitech-dj.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I just put the line

```
/sbin/rmmod hid_logitech_dj
```

in `/etc/rc.local` (above the line `exit 0`).  That way by the time I get to the login page, the `hid_logitech_dj` module is removed already.

The problem I have is that I have to type a password to decrypt the disk during boot, and unfortunately, it looks like the `hid_logitech_dj` module is still loaded at that time, so my keyboard won't work through my Keyboard-video-mouse KVM.  I have to unplug my usb keyboard from the KVM and plug it directly into one of the USB Ports on the motherboard/case.

(I would be interested to know why the `hid_logitech_dj` module causes this problem in the first place, and if there a bug report on this.)

Comment: Hi Mike, rc.local executes at the end of the multiuser runlevel. Can you try to run the script in a lower runlevel?